# Decompilation output modification in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, decompilation, hexrays

I am trying to modify cfunc AST from

```
If (a1 && some_func_ptr) {
  some_func_ptr();
}
```

To

```
if (a1) {
  some_func_ptr();
}
```

But I constantly get INTERR 50683 error. I tried

```
new_item = idaapi.cexpr_t(item.cif.expr.x)
item.cif.expr.swap(new_item)
```

Also many other attempts to modify other parts of AST fail in the same way. I suspect that it has something to do with thisown flag, but various changes did nothing.

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with the Hex-Rays support? While I'd love to see the answer to your question also here in our Q&A, contacting the support is oftentimes faster and leads to better results for very specific questions like this.

Comment: Due to political reasons Hex-Rays support stopped answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 50683 INTERR means address is invalid. There is a check applied by verifier (**\IDAFolder\plugins\hexrays_sdk\verifier\cverify.cpp**) in **cfunc_t::verify_insn** function:

```
case cit_if:
  if ( maturity < CMAT_TRANS1 || maturity >= CMAT_CASTED )
  {
    ea_t jea = i->cif->expr.calc_jmp_cnd_ea();
    if ( jea != BADADDR && i->ea != jea )
      // ctree: mismatch in if-statement and its expression addresses
      CFAIL_QASSERT(50683, i);
  }
```

There are also many other INTERRs for decompilation in case anyone is looking. So, the correct code in my case had to have something like this:

```
new_item = idaapi.cexpr_t(item.cif.expr.x)
new_item.ea = item.cif.expr.ea
# or just new_item.ea = idaapi.BADADDR it works too
item.cif.expr.swap(new_item)
```